# Propagate document properties automatically

Tags: windows

I've set user permissions on a folder in an attempt to have all files within the folder adopt the given permissions. I've also applied the "Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here..." option from the Advanced dialog. The problem is, when I write new files into the folder, they don't adopt the folder's permissions.

Why is this? Can I make files automatically adopt the folder's settings automatically? What is the point and the meaning of folder properties otherwise?

The files are photos being imported from my camera. I'm using Picasa to do the transfer, which I guess is simply copying the files from the camera storage to the selected folder. They are saved to the "Shared Pictures" folder of the "All Users" folder because I want both myself and my wife (separate user accounts) to see them. But all new photos I import are invisible to the other user account until I manually edit the user permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting just sets the permissions on the files and folders in the folder at the point in time when you click to set those permissions.
Folder properties are to control what users can and cannot do.
What sort of files are you trying to put in there that you would want to set the permissions for? What I mean is do they come from an App or do you copy them in there?

Comment: I've edited the question to better describe the files' origin. I suspect you're answer is correct, but I was hoping to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Properties > Security > Advanced

make sure **Inherit from parent the permission entries that apply to child objects.** box is checked.

Comment: and if not. click on edit on the advanced tab to set it